# Graph of function with integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Finding domain, continuity, limits, derivability, convexity, maxima, minima, etc. Where the integral could be intended as improper:

$F(x) = \int_{-2}^x $$e^t \over t^{1 \over 3}(t-2)$ $dt$

I started by integrating the function as I usually do with indefinite integrals but I can't go ahead because the result is not an elementary function.

Comment: The point of the problem is that you can analyze differentiability and all of $F$ without actually computing it explicitly. Have you ever seen a way to compute the derivative of an integral?

Comment: Ok, for derivative. That was the easy part. What about limits, domain, etc.? I really don't know where to start

Comment: I can kind of get how to calculate 2nd derivative to find convexity and critical points after the derivatives. But what then?

Comment: What basically remains is domain, limits and continuity because everything else can be calculated with 1st and 2nd derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:**

Use the $1$st Fundamental Theorem of integral calculus to obtain the $1$st derivative (but  the $2$nd  Fundamental Theorem will not yield the $2$nd derivative ;o)).